# An expression to "take advantage of the success of other person" but not in a negative sense

Tags: single-word-requests

The idea is that three musicians formed a group "taking advantage of" the success of the new rhythm. But it should not be perceived as negative.

Would "they embrace the success of the new rhythm and formed a group"

or

"they seized the success of the new rhythm and formed a group" be correct?

Comment: _Hitch one's wagon to_ is the usual expression. _He hitched his wagon to a winner_ can refer to business, political, or social success reflected on some hanger-on.

Comment: could I use then "they hitched their wagon to the success of the new rhythm..."? and is it a slang or I can use it in academic writings?

Comment: You hitch your wagon to the new rhythm. If it succeeds, so do you. Otherwise, you lose a wheel in the ditch. It's a metaphor.

Comment: "Build on" is often used in such cases.  "They built on the success of the new rhythm ..."  (Though it fits that context a little less well than some others.)

Comment: They all mutually benefitted from the success of one rhythm? Why not make more?

Comment: Both seized and embraced seem correct; also, leveraged, adopted, took up, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in:

> "They **rode** the success of X (the new rhythm/musical genre) and formed Y (a band or musical group)."

to ride - figurative semse  [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ride)

> figurative: be carried or supported by (something moving with great
>   momentum)